# Refactor an oldschool method with 3 loops into a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list of datetime values: weekADates

I have a generic list of TimeTable entities: response.TimeTableWeek

```
public class TimeTable
{
    public int LessonNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// For each day and lessonnumber in the week there is a schooclass code assigned
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<DayOfWeek,string> WeeklySchoolclassCodes { get; set; }
}
```

This code needs to be changed into a LINQ query:

```
var periodList = new List<Period>();
foreach (DateTime date in weekADates)
{
    foreach (TimeTable timetable in response.TimeTableWeek)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timetable.WeeklySchoolclassCodes.Count; i++)
        {
            var p = new Period();
            p.LessonNumber = timetable.LessonNumber + 1;
            p.LessonDate = date;
            p.SchoolclassCode = timetable.WeeklySchoolclassCodes[date.DayOfWeek];
            periodList.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many variations of .Select and .SelectMany but I could not get a solution.

This is how the list of periods would look like.

[image]

How would you change this into linq?

Comment: Why close 2 times? Would you mind to explain?

Comment: If your code works why does it need to be converted to Linq?  Don't get me wrong, Linq is great, but if it isn't broke why fix it.

Comment: Its just for learning purposes... If you do linq and have a problem you often can not take the same approach you did with a for-loop. Its a mind-shift another way of thinking then and only then you can solve the problem with half the lines of code sometimes at least hehe.

Comment: If you Want to convert foreach loops into linq - an easy way is to install R# (resharper) it will do it for you.

Comment: Also look at the massive readability added to the code - a valid point to reactor to Linq in this case.

Comment: @Flowerking This is also one of my reasons changing for-loops to linq because it can be read more fluently/naturally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
periodList.AddRange(
    from date in weekADates
    from timetable in response.TimeTableWeek
    from schoolclassCode in timetable.WeeklySchoolclassCodes.Values
    select new Period
    {
        LessonNumber = timetable.LessonNumber + 1,
        LessonDate = date,
        SchoolclassCode = schoolclasscode
    });
```

Edit: Fixed the third from to take the values from the dictionary, not the KeyValuePairs.

In method style you could write it like this:

```
periodList.AddRange(
    weekADates.SelectMany(date => 
    response.TimeTableWeek.SelectMany(timetable =>
    timetable.WeeklySchoolclassCodes.Values.Select(schoolclassCode =>
    new Period
    {
        LessonNumber = timetable.LessonNumber + 1,
        LessonDate = date,
        SchoolclassCode = schoolclasscode
    })));
```

Comment: ah I did not know that with Linq query style instead of method style I can access the value date from a former query/loop. That was my problem with using Select/SelectMany.

Comment: Do you also have time to refactor this solution (if it works) into a linq method style query? Would really interest me how you would do it.

Comment: Added an example. But I'd really choose the first style, it's way easier to understand (especially when you know SQL).

Comment: argh.... I tried SelectMany and Select and other way round but did not think of SelectMany 2 times then Select hehe, thanks though